# SQL query to update rows based on user defined condition

Tags: sql, sql-update, upsert

I have a table and a condition to match a substring / entire value of two columns.

A sample table is like below

Table1:

```
id           id1    id2              id3        id4
18499       18499   8001480043398   datarow1a   datarow1a
18497       18497   8000900121777   datarow1a   datarow1a
18495       18495   8024180001901   datarow1b   datarow1b
18493       18493   8001480070530   datarow1c   something1c
18573       18573   8001480007703   datarow1b   datarow1b
```

Sample query with user condition:

```
select * 
from table1 
where id3 = id4.
```

Result:

```
id           id1    id2              id3        id4
18499       18499   8001480043398   datarow1a   datarow1a
18497       18497   8000900121777   datarow1a   datarow1a
18495       18495   8024180001901   datarow1b   datarow1b
18573       18573   8001480007703   datarow1b   datarow1b
```

But what I want is to update `id1` to the either min or max id based on user requirement. So if the user chooses min, then id1 of rows 1 and 2 should be like below

```
 id          id1    id2              id3        id4
18499       18497   8001480043398   datarow1a   datarow1a
18497       18497   8000900121777   datarow1a   datarow1a
```

and for rows 3 and 4 it should be

```
18493       18493   8001480070530   datarow1c   datarow1c
18573       18493   8001480007703   datarow1b   datarow1b
```

Can anyone share how I should approach this?

PS: I did not know how to approach using queries, so unable to give any samples. The data base i use does not have full outer join(in case if this info is useful)

Comment: Which version of which database are you using?

Comment: @Abecee I am using Phoenix 4.3.1 used over HBASE.

Comment: You probably should tag accordingly...

Answer (score 0):

For Max:

```
UPDATE table_1 
SET    id1 = (SELECT Max(id1) 
          FROM   table_1 t2 
          WHERE  table_1.id3 = t2.id3) 
WHERE  id3 = id4
```

For Min:

```
UPDATE table_1 
SET    id1 = (SELECT Min(id1) 
          FROM   table_1 t2 
          WHERE  table_1.id3 = t2.id3) 
WHERE  id3 = id4
```

Comment: @ Heshie Jakobovits Thanks for your answer. Can i know how to convert this to use using "upsert" command as there is no set command in the DB i am using.

Comment: Just from looking at the [Phoenix Grammar](https://phoenix.apache.org/language/) I'd try something like `UPSERT INTO table_1 AS t1 (id1, id3, id4) SELECT MAX(t2.id1), t2.id3, t2.id4 FROM table_1 AS t2 WHERE t1.id3 = t2.id3 AND t1.id4 = t2.id4 AND t2.id3 = t2.id4`. Alternatively, I'd consider creating a `VIEW` (or one each for `MIN` and `MAX`) to `SELECT` from. If this doesn't work either, there is still the option to retrieve the values and `UPSERT INTO table_1 (id1, id3, id4) VALUES (min_or_max_value_for_id1, id3_value, id4_value)`. - Sorry no access to an installation to test myself.